# Can't find service header files

Tags: ros-melodic, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can build my project and running `rosservice show benchmark_suite/status` will reveal it has indeed been declared. But I cannot for the life of me find the header fine. The devel/include directory doesn't exist and inserting a `#include "benchmark_suite/status.h"` line in my .cpp file shows a "not found error" when building.

CMakeList.txt excerpts:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rosmsg
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
...
add_service_files(
  FILES
  status.srv
)
...
add_executable(cubic src/cubic.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cubic ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

package.xml excerpts

```
...
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
<exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349052/can%27t-find-service-header-files/) by [nightduck](https://answers.ros.org/users/53420/nightduck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If that is really all you have in your `CMakeLists.txt`, then I believe you're missing a `generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)`.

See [Building messages, services or actions](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html) in the Catkin documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nightduck](https://answers.ros.org/users/53420/nightduck/) on 2020-04-11**:
That was it, thank you. I missed that step in the wiki